# how to set format of date in Windows Forms date time picker?

Tags: c#

any one can guide me how to set the date format for date time picker of VS using c#

i want to set format of 18 January 2010 to 18/01/10.

Comment: Obviously a typo: you'll want to set it to 18/01/10, not 18/01/01 :-)

Comment: I presume you mean the Windows Forms date time picker? Because neither Visual Studio nor C# have a date time picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the *Format* to *Custom* and the *Custom Format* to *dd/MM/yy*

Have a look at

- [DateTimePicker.CustomFormat
  Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx)
- [DateTimePicker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx)

> The Format property sets the
>   DateTimePickerFormat of the control.
>   The default date Format is
>   DateTimePickerFormat.Long. If the
>   Format property is set to
>   DateTimePickerFormat.Custom, you can
>   create your own format style by
>   setting the CustomFormat property and
>   building a custom format string.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
dateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yy";
```

Edited after reading the question properly :P

Answer (score 0):

```
var mytest = (dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString()).Replace("hh",string.Empty).Replace("mm", string.Empty).Replace("ss", string.Empty); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB",mytest);
```